# Early or late argument evaluation in golang?

Tags: go

In my program I do a series of sequential checks in this manner:

```
var value int

if !(ParseOrFail(inputStrVal, &value) &&
     Validate(value)) {
    return SomeErr
}
```

I know that `Validate` is called only if `ParseOrFail` returns true, but I'm not sure whether in all such scenarios it will get the updated value.

Is it correct to do so? Or must I pass a pointer to `Validate` ?

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/l6XHbgQjFs

Comment: Validate is called everytime, it's return value will be evaluated only if the ParseOrFail returns true. Unless ParseOfFail mutates value in a separate go routine Validate will be called with the updated value.

Comment: @mkopriva if the first function return false, the second is not called. Just checked in playground.

Comment: Yup, I take that back :f, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions)
>
> An expression specifies the computation of a value by applying
>   operators and functions to operands.
>
> [Operands](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operands)
>
> Operands denote the elementary values in an expression. An operand may
>   be a literal, a (possibly qualified) non-blank identifier denoting a
>   constant, variable, or function, a method expression yielding a
>   function, or a parenthesized expression.
>
> [Order of evaluation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation)
>
> At package level, initialization dependencies determine the evaluation
>   order of individual initialization expressions in variable
>   declarations. Otherwise, when evaluating the operands of an
>   expression, assignment, or return statement, all function calls,
>   method calls, and communication operations are evaluated in lexical
>   left-to-right order.
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> Given an expression f of function type F,
>
> ```
> f(a1, a2, … an)
> ```
>
> calls f with arguments a1, a2, … an. Except for one special case,
>   arguments must be single-valued expressions assignable to the
>   parameter types of F and are evaluated before the function is called.
>   The type of the expression is the result type of F. A method
>   invocation is similar but the method itself is specified as a selector
>   upon a value of the receiver type for the method.
>
> [Logical operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators)
>
> Logical operators apply to boolean values and yield a result of the
>   same type as the operands. The right operand is evaluated
>   conditionally.
>
> ```
> &&    conditional AND    p && q  is  "if p then q else false"
> ||    conditional OR     p || q  is  "if p then true else q"
> !     NOT                !p      is  "not p"
> ```

The behavior of your code is defined in The Go Programming Language Specification.

```
var value int

if !(ParseOrFail(inputStrVal, &value) && Validate(value)) {
    return SomeErr 
}
```

Or, in pseudocode,

```
ParseOrFail arguments are evaluated
ParseOrFail is called
if ParseOrFail == true
    Validate arguments are evaluated
    Validate is called
```

That is, in your example (https://play.golang.org/p/l6XHbgQjFs), late evaluation.